# Unable to turn off Airplane mode

Tags: android, mode, airplane-mode

I've create an app with a button that allows airplane mode to be toggled on and off. Works fine when turning airplane mode on. But strangely, airplane mode seems to stay on when it is toggled off.

If I check the phone settings after I turn it off, they indicate that airplane mode is off. But the airplane mode icon still shows in the top bar of the phone, and holding down the phone's power button shows that airplane mode is still on.

Not sure why the setting would show as off when it's still on?

Here is the code I'm using to turn it off - I've debugged and it's definitely hitting this. mContext is a variable I'm using to hold the context, this is passed into a settings class which then has methods in for turning airplane mode off and on:

```
System.putInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
this.airplaneOn = false;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", 0);
mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And here's the code I'm using to check the status of airplane mode -

```
public boolean isAirplaneOn() {
  int airplaneMode = 0;
  try {
    airplaneMode = System.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),
  android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (airplaneMode == 1) {
        this.airplaneOn = true;
    } else {
        this.airplaneOn = false;
    }
    return airplaneOn;
}
```

In both cases, this.airplaneOn is a private boolean which stores the status of airplane mode.

Could I be doing something silly here, or is checking this setting somehow unreliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success doing the following code:

```
public static boolean isFlightModeEnabled(Context context) {
    return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
}

public static void toggleFlightMode(Context context) {
    boolean isEnabled = isFlightModeEnabled(context);

    Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The only difference I see between my code and yours is that in your putInt() you have hard-coded 0.

One other thing to be aware of is according to the docs, [ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) is

`This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.`

I haven't had issues with this in the past, but perhaps your device is newer and enforcing something that the older phones I've had success with don't enforce.

Comment: That's cracked it - passing a boolean instead of 0/1 does indeed make it work. Excellent, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean instead of 0/1 for your intent, ie: intent.putExtra("state", true). The code in the other post should work properly.

Comment: Yes it works great - passing the boolean to the intent did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE");

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service state changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                boolean isEnabled = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
            /*   setSettings(context, isEnabled?1:0);
                Intent intent_mode = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
               intent_mode.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent_mode);*/

                if(isEnabled==true)
                { setSettings(context, isEnabled?1:0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flight mode on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                    newIntent.putExtra("state", false);
                    sendBroadcast(newIntent);
                }
                else
                { setSettings(context, isEnabled?1:0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flight mode off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

          }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void setSettings(Context context, int value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                Settings.System.putInt(
                          context.getContentResolver(),
                          Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
            } else {
                Settings.Global.putInt(
                          context.getContentResolver(),
                          Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
            }       

        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;          
        } else {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        }       
    }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);


}
//permissions needed:
```

//  
  //